# Keep only one row from every domain

Tags: r

I have a list of urls likes the following one:
my_full_urls_list

```
 [1] "http://www.mypage1.com"                              
     [2] "http://www.mypage1.com/produce"                              
     [3] "http://www.mypage1.com/contact"                              
     [4] "http://www.mypage2.com"                             
     [5] "http://www.mypage2.com/other"                              
     [6] "http://www.mypage2.com/rye"                             
     [7] "http://www.mypage3.com/contact"                              
     [8] "http://www.mypage3.com/buy"                              
     [9] "http://www.mypage5.com/info"
```

For the previous example I know the domains:

```
 http://www.mypage1.com    
    http://www.mypage2.com
    http://www.mypage3.com
    http://www.mypage5.com
```

And based on this I would like to keep only one value for every domain. Example of output:

```
 "http://www.mypage1.com/produce"
    "http://www.mypage2.com/other"
    "http://www.mypage3.com/contact"
    "http://www.mypage5.com/info"
```

What I have is the list of the domains I want and compared with the my_full_urls_list I would like to keep only one url of every domain.

```
dput(my_full_urls_list)
c("http://www.mypage1.com", "http://www.mypage1.com/produce", 
"http://www.mypage1.com/contact", "http://www.mypage2.com", 
"http://www.mypage2.com/other", "http://www.mypage2.com/rye",
"http://www.mypage3.com/contact", "http://www.mypage3.com/buy",
"http://www.mypage5.com/info")
```

and the list of main urls as the previous dput format:

```
  c("http://www.mypage2.com",
    "http://www.mypage3.com",
    "http://www.mypage5.com",
    "http://www.mypage1.com")
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: @akrun I found a different way to describe my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think you can use `sub` to strip the suffix part and match with the original link, create a group, and use `tapply` to get the first value of each domain.

Comment: @akrun thanks, could I ask for an example?

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to show the data.  It makes it easier to copy/paste the data for testing.

Comment: @akrun I have edit the dput at the end of the question and the dput of main urls

Comment: Posted a solution where `url`  is `my_full_urls_list` and `domains` is the one you are using for matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use regex lookarounds to match one or more characters that succeeds the `.com` to the end of the string and replace it with `''`.  Then, we `match` with the 'domains', use that as grouping variable to get the `sample` of 1 observation from the 'urls'.

```
url1 <- sub("(?<=\\.com).*$", '', urls, perl=TRUE)
tapply(urls, match(url1, domains), FUN= sample, 1)
```

#### Update

If there are `.com`, `.net` etc., we can match the `\` followed by the word (`\\w+`) at the end of the string and replace with `''`.  The rest is same as before.

```
url1 <- sub('\\/\\w+$', '', urls)
tapply(urls, match(url1, domains), FUN= sample, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you this is it possible instead of this `"(?<=\\.com).*$",` I could give the list of domains? I know I didn't show it my example but I have also some with 3 levels of urls like example http:/www.mypage1.com/view/

Comment: @Piggy It is possible.  I just thought using the easiest option given the example.  Can you show a different example where this doesn't work so that I can test it

Comment: @Piggy updated the post.  Please check if that is what you meant.